# Does the system of two equation in two variables given below have a possible real solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, conic-sections, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the following two equations:

$$\sqrt {3x} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x+y} \right) = 2 $$

$$\sqrt{7y}\left(1 -\frac{1}{x+y}\right)= 4\sqrt{2}$$

.
It is expected to verify if the equations possess a solution and if yes what is the floor of $ y/x $ for that solution.

.
What have I tried:

.
Eliminating the $\frac {1}{x+y}$ term from the two equations leads to :
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3x}} + \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{7y}} = 2 $$
Which gives
$$ y = \frac{24x}{7(1- \sqrt{3x})^2}$$
Also from the first equation value of y is :

$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{3x}}{2-\sqrt{3x}} - x $$

Equating the two values of y and simplifying resulted in a polynomial with fractional powers of x. This proved to be a dead end for me.

.
Note: some underlying inquisitions:

1. Is there a method for simplifying such equations that I am unaware of?
2. Are the given two equations representing hyperbola? (Checked the graph on desmos!). If yes how can one see that without referring to the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Moo's comment $$1323 x^4+3024 x^3+2610 x^2-7456 x+147 = 0$$ is the same as
$$\left(9 x^2+30 x+49\right) \left(147 x^2-154 x+3\right)=0$$ The first quadratic does not show real roots and for the second
$$x_\pm=\frac{11\pm4 \sqrt{7}}{21} $$
Similarly
$$3087 y^4-25284 y^3+44716 y^2-38816 y+4032 = 0$$is the same as
$$\left(63 y^2-120 y+112\right)\left(49 y^2-308 y+36\right)=0 $$
The first quadratic does not show real roots and for the second
$$y_\pm=\frac{2\left(11\pm 4 \sqrt{7}\right)}{7} =6 x_\pm$$

Comment: Thank you so much for building over @Moo’s comment. @Moo seems to have removed his comment, so i thank him here too.

Comment: I have a few concerns (with the presented solution) though that I wish to put forward:

Comment: 1) The two bi-quadratic equations are too daunting (to me) to be factorised into product of quadratics as shown above. I wish to know how @Claude Leibovici did it. 2) The solution presented is absolutely perfect as far as correctness is concerned, however I look forward to seeing an approach that involves less work. The reason for this is , the problem is taken from a national Indian maths competition that allows around 5 minute of time for one problem which I hope we will agree is not the required time of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, the curves cannot be hyperbolas.

The first equation is necessarily a subset of the locus of points satisfying $3x(x+y+1)^2 = 4(x+y)^2$, and similarly for the second, $7y(x+y-1)^2 = 8(x+y)^2,$ which are plotted in the neighborhood of $[-1,1]^2$ below.

[image]

The first curve is tangent to the $y$-axis, and the second tangent to the $x$-axis (both easily verified through implicit differentiation).  When zoomed out, we see:

[image]

So this suggests that the given equations cannot be sections of hyperbolae.  They may be *asymptotic* to conic sections, but their degree is $3$, not $2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the neat illustrations :)